# I wondered if there is any way to make this line of code shorter: for x in letter

Tags: python, for-loop, brute-force

I wondered if there is any way to shorten this line of code(it's underneath this text).

I want to try for a, then b, then c, d, e, f, g and after that aa, ab, ac etc. etc.

I have python 3.7.

I want to use it in some sort of brute force thing.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
keyboard = Controller()
time.sleep(2)
for i in range(20):
    for x in range(letters):
            keyboard.type(x)
            keyboard.type(y)
            keyboard.press(Key.enter)
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: What error do you get when you run this?

Comment: It's not that i get an error, but that i wanted help with this code, because i am a beginner python programmer, but i mean a real beginner, as in not knowing what itertools is... a friend of mine recommended this site, so i went on right to it, but i don't really dont know how or what... Sorry...

Comment: Maybe i explained it wrong, i wanted a program that tries every possible combination, but i don't really know what to do! Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

This line of code:

```
for x in range(letters):
```

Should not work. This will throw a `TypeError` since `range` expects one, two or three integers, not a list of strings.

Here's a solution using a generator which you can modify to suit your needs. The generator uses `itertools.product` to yield tuples containing strings. The number of strings corresponds to the `number_of_digits` keyword-parameter. Using `itertools.islice` you can grab the next n-tuples (where `n` in this case is 5) - it might be convenient to grab only a certain amount of tuples, since 26 ** 2 == 676 (assuming `number_of_digits` is 2).

```
def main():

    from itertools import islice

    def get_product(*, number_of_digits=2):
        from itertools import product
        from string import ascii_lowercase

        for tpl in product(*[ascii_lowercase] * number_of_digits):
            yield tpl

    product_generator = get_product()

    for tpl in islice(product_generator, 5):
        print(tpl)


    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
('a', 'a')
('a', 'b')
('a', 'c')
('a', 'd')
('a', 'e')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But is there any way to type this at the cursor position, like i did in the example?